# MVC - Switch View based on User Role

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a requirement in my MVC application to present the user with a different view of an action based on their role. What is the best way to do this?

Currently I have the following code which I do not like:

```
if (HttpContext.User.IsInRole("Admin"))
    return View("Details.Admin", model);
else if (HttpContext.User.IsInRole("Power"))
    return View("Details.Power", model);

//default
return View("Details", model);
```

Would this be a good fit for an Action Filter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Would this be a good fit for an Action Filter?

Absolutely:

```
public class MyActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        var result = filterContext.Result as ViewResultBase;
        if (result != null)
        {
            var user = filterContext.HttpContext.User;
            if (user.IsInRole("Admin"))
            {
                result.ViewName = string.Format("{0}.Admin", filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName);
            }
            else if (user.IsInRole("Power"))
            {
                result.ViewName = string.Format("{0}.Power", filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or you could even build a custom view engine.

Comment: I don't think I have enough instances of this occurring to warrant creating a view engine, but I was figuring the action filter approach would probably be good. Thanks Darin